# Merge sort and Inversion algorithm

Tags: c, mergesort, inversion

Okay, my question is to find the number of inversions in a given array.

After reading the inversion algorithm, I figured that i just needed to add 1 line of code to the mergesort algorithm that I had written a few days back.

This worked perfectly for small array sizes but somehow when I'm scaling the array upto a 100000 integers, the answer is incorrect

Here is the merge function to which I added that one line.

```
int merge(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int arr1[11];
    int arr2[11];
    for(i=0;i<mid-low+1;i++)
        arr1[i]=arr[low+i];
    for(j=0;j<high-mid;j++)
        arr2[j]=arr[mid+1+j];
    arr1[i]=9999999;
    arr2[j]=9999999;    
    i=0;
    j=0;
    for(k=low;k<=high;k++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<=arr2[j])
        {
            arr[k]=arr1[i];
            i++;
        }   
        else
        {
            {
                arr[k]=arr2[j];
                j++;
                count=count+mid-low+1-i; //Inversion counter. 
            }
        }       
    }
    return(0);  
}
```

Can anyone please tell me as to what is wrong with this?

I've spent hours trying to figure it out, but have had no luck with it. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `assert (mid-low+1) <= 10` and similar for j,mid,high.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited the code.

I just realised that writing     i<mid-low+1 and j<high-mid is redundant.

Could you please check it again?

The answers for small cases is perfect.

Comment: the first two loops `for(i=0;i<mid-low+1;i++) arr1[i]=arr[low+i];` (similar for j,mid,high) also suffer from the same phenomenon.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with those loop initializers.

I verified again, and the sub-arrays that are being merged through these loops contain all the valid elements.

Comment: But they do assume that `mid-low+1 < 10` and that `high-mid < 10` The "999999"  assignments after the loop stretch the boundaries even more.

Comment: Yes. The end initializations are seem a little weird. But they are necessary for the merging loop.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANKS!
All I had to do was change it from 10 to 11.
You were right it was going out of bounds. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like an overflow error. What size are your ints? Try using a larger type for your counter.

Comment: Sounds like the exercise from [Stanford online course Design and Analysis of Algorithms I](https://www.coursera.org/algo/auth/welcome).

Answer (score -1):

```
long long int count[200200];

int merge()
{
       long long int a[200200],n,left,right,e,i;
       scanf("%lld",&n);
       for( i = 0 ; i< n ; i++)
       {
               scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
               count[i] = 0;
           }
    long long int size,l1,h1,l2,h2,j,k,temp[200200];
    for(size = 1 ; size < n ; size = size *2)
    {
        l1 = 0;
        k = 0;
        while(l1 + size < n)
        {
            h1 = l1 + size - 1;
            l2 = h1 + 1;
            h2 = l2 + size - 1;
            if(h2 >=n )
            h2 = n - 1;
            i =l1;
            j =l2;
            left = count[h1];
            right= count[h2];
            e = 0; 
            while( i <= h1 && j <= h2)
            {
                if(a[i] <= a[j])
                {
                    temp[k++] = a[i++];
                }
                else
                {
                    e = e + h1 - i + 1;
                    temp[k++] = a[j++];
                }
            }
            count[h2] = left + right + e;
            while(i<=h1)
                temp[k++]=a[i++];
            while(j<=h2)
                temp[k++]=a[j++];
            for( i = l1 ; i <= h2 ;i++)
        //    printf("%d ",temp[i]);
        //    printf("\n");
            l1 = h2 + 1;
        }
        for(i = l1 ; k < n ; i++)
        {
            temp[k++] = a[i];
        }
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
        //    printf(" %d = %d ",i,count[i]);
            a[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n\n",count[n-1]);
    return 0;
}



int main()
{

      merge(); 
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice wall of code, now explain what it does and how it works.